# ImageView is not getting shown in the Linear Layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to display a textview and 2 imageviews in an xml which to be used as a view for a list item in the ListView.
It should be like this pattern:

TextView                                                        ImageView
                                                                ImageView

But my imageviews are not getting displayed.

My layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/flowerName"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >


       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:id="@+id/shareImage"
           android:src="@drawable/share"
           />

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:id="@+id/idImage"
           android:src="@drawable/white_star"

           />



   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: revise your layout. it has many flaws. For example what you tried to achieve Text Image Image cannot be done with the layout you just created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using weight.
Global layout would have a 100 `weightSum`. `TextView` a 90 `weight` and your layout holding ImageView 10, with `gravity` end.

Using Weight, you are sure all your view will be visible whatever the screen size is.

Something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/flowerName"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/shareImage"
            android:src="@drawable/share"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/idImage"
            android:src="@drawable/white_star"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

textview might be taking all space reduce width. it should work.

Comment: That's right. Still it is not a correct and viable solution. Phones and tablets have different screen size and density. The solution here is to use weight. And avoid using dp values.

Comment: yeah using weight for simple layouts is fine. but there are more options like using PercentageRelativeLayout optimized for these things. [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Comment: Well in this scenario I guess weight is ideal. He will do whatever is best for him

Comment: agree there i was mentioning different approaches.